# Qt stylesheet ignored at runtime

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qtstylesheets

I am trying to set the size of a radio button indicator with a style sheet like so:

```
QRadioButton::indicator { 
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px;
}
```

In the designer, this shows up correctly. However, when I actually run the app the indicators revert to the normal size. All other entries in the style sheet show up correctly at runtime. Why is this portion of the stylesheet working in the designer but not at runtime? How can I fix it? There are no other stylesheets in my app that that affect radio buttons.

How the radio button appears in designer:

[image: How the radio button appears in designer]

How the radio button appears at runtime:

[image: How the same radio button appears at runtime]

The sizing got weird, sorry. But you can clearly see that the indicator is much larger in relation to the text in the pic taken from the designer.

Comment: have you set a style? try with `app->setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: @eyllanesc I put that line in my main.cpp and it didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: You could place an image of what you get in the Qt designer and another where you see the problem.

Comment: @eyllanesc I added screen caps to the question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: what is yout OS?

Comment: Developing on Ubuntu 16.04, deploying to Debian 8

Comment: To be sure there is no other QSS applied you could set this in C++ directly on the widget as late as possible and see if it is applied, maybe add a basic QSS (like changing the colour) to check it is actually parsed and used.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you need to look for when using designer.

Now to quick check.

```
//Add this lines and try again
QRadioButton *obj = new QRadioButton()

obj->setObjectName("test");

//If your using qss/css file for styling things...
#test QRadioButton::indicator { 
width: 25px; 
height: 25px;
}
```

Few more inputs...
Font size of text attached to QRadioButton also check changing by some more pixel and check what sort of changes shown to your widget.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If I add a line specifying the border as well as the width and height, it shows up correctly at run time. `QRadioButton::indicator { 
 width: 50px; 
 height: 50px;
 border: 1px solid darkgray;
}` any ideas as to why specifying the border would matter?